# Using uint64_t in 32 bit application

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

Due to some libraries, I have to compile my application in 32 bit, but I need to use integer variables that exceed the max number of 32 bit types. So for example if I try to use `uint64_t` I get an overflow at `2147483647`.

I thought it is possible to use 64 bit integer variables in 32 bit application, so what did I miss here? Do I have to include some specific header oder do I have to set some option therefore? Using VS17.

EDIT:

I did some testing, and in this example program, I can reproduce my overflow problem.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        std::printf("%d\n",i);
        i += (uint64_t)10000;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you are getting overflow at 2147483647 with `uint64_t`? That isn't right. I guess what you're missing is some other bug in your code, but without seeing that code it's hard to help. Post the code that makes you think you are getting an `int32_t` overflow when using `uint64_t`. It should be straightforward to use 64 bit integer variables in a 32 bit program.

Comment: can I suppose you used a literal like in `uint64_t v = 2147483648;` ? By default a literal is an _int_ so you have to use `uint64_t v = 2147483648u;` or `uint64_t v = 68719476735ull;` etc

Comment: @john: You are right, I tested it in a new project. It does not happen there. I am confused now what causes it in my other application.

Comment: to your edit: `std::printf("%d\n",(uint64_t)i);` should produce a warning that the size of the format (32 bits) does not match the real argument

Comment: value of `i` is fine, the print is wrong

Comment: But assuming your problem is not with printing, it is most likely some arithmetic expression. Literals default to ordinary int and the type of the right-hand-side expression is determined by types on rhs, even if you have a larger type on the left. It is all to easy to produce an overflow by arithmetics.

Comment: @jakub_d: Thanks. `cout` did also not produce this problem. Solved.

Comment: So arm yourself with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion and go over all your computations :)

Comment: You have `#include <iostream>` in your code but then you're using `printf()`? :-P

Comment: @Nikos C.: I like to use `printf()` because it does give you possibility to alter the output format. Also I did try `cout`.

Comment: @Lemonbonbon `std::cout` also gives you possibility to alter the output format.

Comment: How to correctly print a value of the types __int64, size_t, and ptrdiff_t: https://www.viva64.com/en/k/0046/

Comment: std::cout is far more flexible and safer. There are many things you can't do with printf. The only advantage of printf is the shorter syntax for formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is here:

> ```
> std::printf("%d\n",i);
>              ^^
> ```

You've used the wrong format specifier, and therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined. `%d` is for `signed int`. You need to use

```
std::printf("%" PRIu64 "\n",i);
```

`PRIu64` is declared in `<cinttypes>`.

P.S. You also haven't included the header which declares `std::printf`.

Comment: so if I expect long value exceeds 32bit, then size_t is bad, and uint64_t is good. right?(i mean in 32bit build) And when we use size_t, in both 32bit and 64bit?

Comment: `And when we use size_t, in both 32bit and 64bit?` We typically use `size_t` to represent sizes of objects or indices of arrays.